# Cинтаксис clientX

Tags: javascript

```
e=document.body.clientX+20+'px'; alert (e);
```

Результат на экране: `NaNpx`. А ожидалось: координаты мыши относительно окна браузера + 20 + "px". Что поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С синтаксисом тут все нормально. Просто clientX отсутствует в document.body, вот его значение и неопределено. Если вы отталкиваетесь от координат мыши, то, видимо, это все происходит в обработчике событий мыши, тогда должно быть что-то вроде

```
e = event.clientX + 20 + 'px'; alert (e);
```

где event - это то, что пришло в обработчик.

Comment: Был один очко, отдал вам, спасибо ) заработало... правда, не понял, что это за объект event.

Answer (score 0):

[Ссылка на ресурс](http://kobru.ru/view_post4.php?id=49)